# CodeIgniter and DataMapper ORM

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I am using the basic login manager that is in the example bugs application but my main admin controller now has about 25 functions in it and at the start of every function i need to call

```
 $this->login_manager->check_login(1);
```

Is there a simple way of having this check done automatically in every function or will I have to go down the MY_Controller route and then inherit from that.

My current constructor looks like this

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller
 {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('login_manager', array('autologin' => FALSE, 'required_group' => 1));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute the login before and after controller login in any framework. To achive this, you can chhose one of these option:

- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

  ```
  $hook['pre_controller'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'MyClass',
    'function' => 'Myfunction',
    'filename' => 'Myclass.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'   => array('beer', 'wine', 'snacks')
  );

  $hook['pre_controller'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'MyOtherClass',
    'function' => 'MyOtherfunction',
    'filename' => 'Myotherclass.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'   => array('red', 'yellow', 'blue')
  );
  ```
- Or you can choose configuration filter: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Filters_system
- Or last simple method: http://forrst.com/posts/CodeIgniter_before_after_controller_action-Diy

Hope it will work for you :)